# Сканирование активных точек wifi

Tags: android

Как мне реализовать поиск каналов на которых работают активные точки wifi  и их загруженность?
Частоту на которой работает точка находить , можно просто каждой частоте присвоить номер канала, как вариант но тогда как проверять загруженность канала?

Comment: А что такое "загруженность канала"? кол-во пользователей на этом канале?

Comment: Можно и так сказать

Comment: Тогда Вам придется разобораться  с тем, как к точке подключиться и в админке посмотреть это. Некоторые точки умеют по telnet отдавать. Но это будет для каждой точки свой способ плюс нужно иметь креды.

Comment: А не подключаясь к точке как-то можно узнать?

Comment: Может есть способ другой, не узнавая количество устройств подключённых к точке

Comment: Некоторые роутеры предоставляют SNMP. Но это не все, и не факт, что так просто можно получить.

Comment: Буду смотреть спасибо